# The linear model in R ignores entirely one value in the interaction estimation

Tags: r, lm, interaction

I am running a linear model on the impact of a particular team composition on the performance of teams. I have included the region as a separate variable since I plan to compare the coeeficients afterwards. I run the model with interactions between the strategy and every single region. That is what the code for the model looks like. `lm(Kills~Solocarry + Region:Solocarry, unidt)` This is the result I get

```
                             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                    26.8390     0.6221  43.139  < 2e-16 ***
SolocarryTRUE                  -3.0468     1.4180  -2.149  0.03178 *  
SolocarryFALSE:RegionEurope     0.9498     0.8943   1.062  0.28833    
SolocarryTRUE:RegionEurope     -3.3712     1.7146  -1.966  0.04942 *  
SolocarryFALSE:RegionKorea     -3.2339     0.8861  -3.649  0.00027 ***
SolocarryTRUE:RegionKorea      -7.6628     1.7591  -4.356 1.39e-05 ***
SolocarryFALSE:RegionNAmerica  -1.0089     0.8876  -1.137  0.25581    
SolocarryTRUE:RegionNAmerica   -7.1216     1.7591  -4.048 5.36e-05 ***
SolocarryFALSE:RegionOceania    0.6659     0.8927   0.746  0.45581    
SolocarryTRUE:RegionOceania    -1.5712     1.7146  -0.916  0.35959
```

And here you can see that the last one region (that is Brazil) is missing. In the beginning, I thought that Brazil is included as an intercept, but all the other regions have both estimates for True and False for the solocarry coefficient, so shouldn't I have at least something like SolocarryTRUE:RegionBrazil or SolocarryFALSE:RegionBrazil? When I check it with the unique function, I receive this.

```
> unique(unidt$Region)
[1] "Europe"   "NAmerica" "Korea"    "Brazil"   "Oceania"
```

There are 400 observations for each of the regions (except North America but there are 399). When I open the data frame, I can see that it is still there. I have already tried turning it off and on again. Has anybody seen something like this? If yes or you have any idea how to solve it, I would appreciate your help.

Comment: I guess Brazil is the reference group in your treatment contrasts.

Comment: Ad Edward points out, this is because Brazil is the reference group. `SolocarryFALSE:RegionBrazil` is simply the intercept. `SolocarryTRUE:RegionBrazil` is the intercept plus `SolocarryTRUE`. You can always drop the intercept,if you wish, by specifying `lm(Kills~Solocarry + Region:Solocarry - 1, unidt)`.

Comment: Thank you very much. This does solve my problem entirely.